# What Android APIs do I need to perform a USB control transfer (setup, data, status) on a HID device?

Tags: android, usb, device, hid

I am developing the driver for a **USB HID controller** linked to my Android device using USB-host.
All vendor-specific operations enabling me to poll the status of the controller, or to set different flags, are defined as **vendor-specific control commands** which contain a **setup** stage and a **data** stage (device -> controller). Depending on the different commands, the controller may send back a **status** stage message.

I understood that the method **UsbDeviceConnection.controlTransfer()** shall be used to send the setup and data stages. What I don't understand is what method/API I should use to read the status sent back by the controller.

Does someone know?

Thank you very much!

Comment: There isn't much data transferred in the status stage; the device pretty much just indicates whether the transfer succeeded or not.  Probably the only indication you get of a failure in the status stage would be an exception getting raised, or an error code being returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the well-known open source project https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android, that method returns -1 if there's something wrong.

`int result = mConnection.controlTransfer(FTDI_DEVICE_OUT_REQTYPE, SIO_RESET_REQUEST, SIO_RESET_SIO, 0 /* index */, null, 0, USB_WRITE_TIMEOUT_MILLIS);
    if (result != 0) {
        throw new IOException("Reset failed: result=" + result);
    }`

(Code extracted from **FtdiSerialDriver.java**)

I know it, because that's what is happening to me !!